# Caching options with Waf (WAFCACHE and/or ccache)

Tags: build, waf, ccache

For a project, where Waf is used, I want to try some build speedup. I see that waf has a `WAFCACHE` option. So, is `WAFCACHE` sufficient, or do I need to setup `ccache` additionally ? (can they work together), or does `WAFCACHE`[internally] makes use of `ccache`? (I don't see any explanation on this, in the Waf book)

--
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is a really old question, but for others who are curious - you don't need to set up ccache if you use WAFCACHE.  I'm not sure the exact mechanism waf uses, but it does it for all (or at least most) targets.  This was a huge plus for us as we got object cacheing for our Fortran code for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering if I could use ccache for building RTEMS with Waf. I have asked about this on the RTEMS forum: [Caching build objects: Waf and ccache](https://www.mail-archive.com/users@rtems.org/msg03314.html) . It turned out that doing a simple trick like this does the job:

> To wrap the compiler using ccache, override the environment variables during the configuration:

```
CXX='ccache gxx' CC='ccache gcc' waf configure
```